# Post from different (strongly typed) views to the same controller's action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC5 application I have X different `Views` strongly typed to X different `Models`.
I want to post these X different models from those X different views to the same action on `HomeController` and to be able to distinguish between the models and to get their respective data inside this action.

I want to avoid using X if statements and switch statement with X cases ..
I thought of an empty interface to be implemented by all these models but it's said to be a "code smell" ..

```
public ActionResult CommonAction (?)
{
   ....
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: if(object is A){ A a = (A)object; }

Comment: @JuryGolubev, if I have 10 different types then I'll have 10 `if` statements or a `switch` statement  with 10 cases .. it's not something I want ..

Comment: Well you don't actually define what you want ). You asked "how to distinguish". Here you go. If you have 100500 classes to get some similar value from, use Interface. Or give some better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: You are right! I edited my question!